# Not able to animate SVG the way I want

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm pretty new to SVG and how to work with them. I am not asking you for answer code, what I am asking is for some guide on maybe some plugin, maybe an article or some advice on how do I go about animating this SVG the way I wish to.

```
Problem:
```

I want to animate the picture below of the Sun, I'll be creating a vector graphic of this image obviously but what **I want is these cuts in the bottom part of sun to animate and go from top to bottom revealing the background and second sun behind the main sun.**

I want to do this inside a webpage so I need help regarding that.

Like I am not able to figure out how would I go about the whole process of making these cuts going down. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: For the animation please check this pen: [vapor sun](https://codepen.io/DavidJAldred/pen/xoNZLV) As for the second sun - apparently is part of the radial gradient behind the main sun

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you so much,

Comment: @Paulie_D sir pardon me I didn't know that. I asked for a reference as I didn't want to get the answer right away and wanted to learn it by trying myself since I wasn't getting and idea how to go about it I asked here. Just so that I could get started

Answer (score 1):

I would try https://rive.app/

As far as the how, I would create a short infinite loop. The horizontal bars would probably need to be their own shapes with some kind of masking effect on them to knock out the circle. You'd have to tween them to move up on the Y axis and let the height shrink to nothing as it moves up. The animation would probably only be 250-750ms. Let me know if that works!

Comment: I'll try it out. you told me name of a good app, I'll have to see some tutorials on it. I'll be sure to update you. Thank you so much